# Collision detection with images on the iPhone using OpenGL

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, 2d, collision-detection

I'm working on a 2D game (kind of like a top down space shooter) for the iPhone using an engine very similar to cocos2d (not exactly though) on OpenGL ES. I'm trying to figure out how I'm going to do collision detection.

All the ships for my game are images, and the game will load the image as a texture onto the screen. I've got *very very* simple detection going already that basically just takes the rectangles of the images and checks to see if those collide and can do that just fine.

But, of course the ship isn't perfectly taking up the entire rectangle so there is whitespace in there. So my question is how am I supposed to account for that whitespace? Do I have to have the matrices of the ships stored? Or is there another way? I've also heard of possibly using the Chipmunk physics engine for collision detection? How would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) regarding Chipmunk, the short answer is ***yes you should immediately download chipmunk, donate something to the bloke, and start learning about it***.

Working with that for a day or so will basically answer all the questions you have. If you want to work with physics games you're going to need to get in to it.

(2) you ask about using an approximation ("just" a rectangle) instead of something more accurately shaped like your spaceships.  ***In fact, you'll be perhaps amazed to learn, that is precisely how it is usually done*** in all your famous big-name games you've played since we were all kids!  Indeed sometimes you might use little more than A DOT (!) to detect collisions.

What you'd probably do in production is try a more complicated model, and play with it for a few hours and see, is it actually any better to play with than your simple dot or rectangle model.

***If you do want to make a more complicated model -- just make one***!  Build it up from three or four rectangles using your current system. Try them "all against each other", and have "one big one to check first" to see if it is even anywhere near each other (sort of a simple spatial hashing).

You will find that when you do it with Chipmunk, which as you now know you have to immediately begin after reading this message, you just build it up the same tedious way. It's not a magic bullet.  But if you were going to use a "more complicated model" yes it is better to go with something standard, chipmunk, to do the work in - it will get done quicker and better. There is heaps to learn and you should hop to it!

(3) ***Unity is not just for 3D*** Finally if you want to do it the smart-ass grown up way, you'd have to use Unity3D which will let you access the very metal, the Nvidia physics on the chipset. Note that unity works perfectly for 2D games also - you just click one button in unity to use a 2D projection (many brand-name ifone 2D games are done exactly like that).

If you use that approach, you can (if you want) have "absolutely exact" physics, with every nook and cranny of your model modelled.

What is the downside to doing this? Ah hah ... well the thing is, you need superb actual 3D models of all the stuff in your game! (Like you see them building in the "how we made the movie" special features that come with your favourite Pixar blu-ray.)  To do that you need things like autodesk, maya and the like. you would quite likely buy some models ready-made from a digital prop shop (no need to build "a chair" as it has been done 1000 times already and you can buy one for ten dollars).

(Unity3D is completely free to use for a few months while you see if it can make you money.)

*Incidentally on the Chipmunk front --- you can just use Corona which is ridiculously easy to use and has chipmunk-like physics completely built in with zero effort on your part! You could have the whole game done in less time than it took to write this email.  You could be selling your game already and thinking up the next one. Or, you could use "Cocos" which indeed has a chipmunk-like physics library built-in .. personally (just me) I do not like and won't touch cocos - but of course many games use it.*

*(It seems pointless, to me, using cocos which is a "for idiots" product, when you can just go ahead and use Corona, which is a "for idiots" product but stupendously easier to use, 1000x more solid, and probably literally 10x faster to finish your product and start making money.)*

**Noel Summary:**

***So in some sense using Unity3D*** (and hence, the actual nvidia physics on your computer's chips) is the ultimate solution if you want detailed nook-and-cranny collisions.  ***Going down one step, Chipmunk is exactly, precisely what you should be using*** on the ifone/ipad for 2D physics -- it is precisely what is used in all the famous games we know so well. You have a bit of learning to do so hop to it - it's superfun. ***Finally go right ahead and just make your current model more complicated*** if you wish - roll your own by adding more rectangles!

And ***the fourth point is, be sure to remember that in games, astonishingly, you can often get away with remarkably simple physics*** (often SIMPLER!! than one rectangle - just a damn point - ie, simply measuring the distance between centers!)  ***Fifthly after going to all the effort of testing more detailed physics, you would play test one against each other***, and find out what is the simplest physics you can get away with.